# Servidor local no acepta conexión mediante método PDO de PHP

Tags: php, pdo, xampp, autenticación, vscode-live-server

Estoy tratando de realizar una conexión con mi localhost mediante el método PDO de PHP, pero me sale el error:
[image: error]

Para esto, estoy utilizando vscode con la extensión live server y xampp con php 7.4; la cosa es que cuando realizo una conexión con el método mysqli, se realiza la conexión sin problemas, pero al usar el método PDO ya no se permite la conexión.

Ahora, subí la base de datos y la pagina a un servidor web gratuito, y desde ahí la conexión si funciona correctamente. Mi código es el siguiente:

[image: codigo]

Las soluciones que ya he explorado son:

1. validacion de los datos de conexión
2. verificar que los servicios de apache y mysql estén corriendo
3. verificar los puertos de los servicios apache y mysql
4. agregar contraseña al usuario
5. agregar un nuevo usuario con todos los privilegios y con contraseña
6. verificar y modificar los valores de los archivos de configuración: php.ini, apache
   httpd.conf, phpmyadmin (config.inc.php) y my.ini
7. actualizar versiones de xampp y de php
8. verificar servicios y extensiones instaladas y habilitadas en PHP para el uso de PDO
9. revisar (demasiados para llevar una cuenta) videos de youtube, blogs, foros y preguntas relacionadas en stack overflow, pero no he encontrado respuesta que me ayude
10. algunos colegas estudiantes me han apoyado buscando información, verificando mis sistemas y sus características, también tratando de implementar las posibles soluciones antes mencionadas, pero el problema sigue.

Como mencione, de manera local, el método mysqli funciona correctamente pero el método PDO no y al subir mis archivos a un host gratuito, la conexión mediante el método PDO también funciona correctamente , lo que me lleva a pensar que existe un problema, ya sea de vscode o de xampp con respecto al método PDO o algo con respecto al enlace entre el IDe y el servidor local.

Agradeceré cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar

Comment: podrías probar usando 127.0.0.1 en vez de localhost?

Comment: Tú phpMyAdmin tiene clave de acceso?

Comment: Hola, gracias por su interés; 
1. Ya probé otros usuarios para hacer la conexión, incluyendo también indicar la ip del servidor en lugar del nombre, así como también, crear e ingresar al usuario pma para desarrollo local.
2. Mi phpmyadmin no tiene clave, pero ya intente realizar la conexión agregando una clave a varios de los usuarios que tengo registrados, también cree un nuevo usuario con contraseña, incluso, borre los usuarios principales y los volví a crear, pero el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: También he intentado modificar los privilegios, usuarios, contraseñas y hasta reparar las tablas de las BD, todo esto desde CMD y no he tenido resultado

Comment: Y a medida que has ido probando esos otros escenarios el mensaje siguió siendo exactamente el mismo? Porque en ese caso es cosa de brujería. Y si no es el caso, pero no explicas cómo varía el error, es en cambio cosa de adivinación.

Comment: El error siempre fue el mismo, al usar contraseña solo cambiaba la palabra (using password: YES), al quitar la contraseña volvía a "NO".

También cambiaba el mensaje de error cuando ingresaba deliberadamente otra contraseña, otro nombre de usuario o de servidor, pero todos ello incorrectos, en ese caso el mensaje de error cambiaba pero me indicaba que no se encontraba o que no existía el valor que yo había modificado.

Sin embargo, el mensaje de error siempre ha sido el mismo, no cambio o menciono algo que me pudiera indicar el posible error que esta sucediendo.

Comment: ¿Y si quitas la coma despues de `dbname=$dbname` tambien te ocurre?  No se que pinta allí esa coma. Y por favor, no uses imágenes para poner código en la pregunta porque cuesta mucho más ayudarte de ese modo. Pega siempre el código como texto, gracias. Léete [ask].

Comment: Hola de nuevo, pido disculpas por el error en el código en donde se muestra una coma, fue un error de dedo al momento de tomar la captura, pero en realidad esa coma no debería existir.
Ahora, quiero comentarle que ya deje por la paz ese error, agarre otro pc, instale vscode y xaamp y trabaje desde ahí, y sin problemas, usando el mismo código. Lo que hare ahora será desinstalar completamente xaamp de mi equipo y volverlo a instalar desde cero para ver si se corrige, esto será en los próximos días. Si alguien tiene alguna idea de que pueda provocar el error, agradecería que lo mencionara.

Comment: Pues si no es la coma y dices que te funciona bien en otro equipo entonces tiene que ser que el usuario `root` necesita password en ese PC y/o permisos de acceso a las bases de datos a las cuales quieres acceder (GRANT) (mientras que en el otro pues no lo necesita). Por lo que sea tienes puesta una password para el usuario `root` en tu MySQL en el PC que te da problemas y no se la estás pasando al script cuando haces la conexión. La password del root no tiene porque ser la misma del sistema, ojo, y quizas la puedes encontrar en los archivos de configuración del mysql (my.cnf o parecidos).

Comment: Pues ya he modificado a los usuarios y sus privilegios, también he verificado que mi usuario 'root' tenga todos (grant) los privilegios en todas las bases de datos pero no me permite el acceso.

Comment: **Actualización 15/03/2022**

Hace 4 días que intento publicar una nueva respuesta pero  stackoverflow me ha bloqueado por actividad sospechosa;

Les tengo nueva información; Siguiendo la lógica de la respuesta que me dio "masterguru", les comento que:

En mi pc tengo instalado MySQL Workbench configurado en el puerto 3306 y XAMPP configurado en el puerto 3307.

Así que hice una prueba modificando el password que utilizo en XAMPP por el que utilizo en Workbench y cambiando el nombre de la Bd por una BD que también tengo en la carpeta de Workbench, el resultado: 

**Conexión Exitosa**

Comment: Entonces, que alguien me explique ¿como indicarle al programa que quiero que abra un enlace entre VSCode y XAMPP? y es que, como les indique en mensajes anteriores, al hacer la conexión mediante el método mysqli, si se conecta a la base de datos "escuela", la cual esta dentro de la carpeta htdocs de XAMPP.
```{
    "php.validate.executablePath": "C:/xampp/php/php.exe",
    "php.executablePath": "C:/xampp/php/php.exe",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    }```

Comment: ```
    "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai",
    "vsicons.dontShowNewVersionMessage": true,
    "bracket-pair-colorizer-2.depreciation-notice": false,
    "phpserver.phpPath": "",
    "workbench.editor.untitled.hint": "hidden"
}
```

Comment: Si alguien tiene una idea de como hacer para que vscode se conecte al servidor de xampp y no al de workbench mediante el método PDO, se lo agradeceré. Anexo código de conexión a la BD;

 ```
<?php
$server='127.0.0.1';
$user = 'root';
$pass ='';
//$port= '3307';
$dbname='escuela';

try{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;port:3307;dbname=$dbname", $user);
    echo "Conexion establecida";
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo("Conexion no establecida, error: " .$e->getMessage());
}

Comment: Pues ni idea, no uso XAMPP pero entiendo que solo estas corriendo un servidor de base de datos, no?  es decir, el que corre en el puerto 3306 deberia valerte... eso del puerto 3307 no entiendo que es, quizas ahi esta el error y tienes que modificar ese 3307 por el 3306 y listo, pero ni idea de donde se tiene que hacer, imagino que en algun archivo ini del xampp ese.

Comment: Eso de los boqueos de stackoverflow a mi me ha pasado cuando he tenido muchas pestañas abiertas apuntando a diferentes pages de su red, pero solo me ha durado unos minutos... quizas a ti te pase si tienes distintos dispositivos haciendo lo mismo sin darte cuenta